# error: no viable conversion from 'tuple<[...], std::__1::tuple<unsigned long long, unsigned long long>>' to 'const tuple<[...], uint_type>'

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm trying to implement Ackerman function using a `tuple` of `unsinged long long`

This is the line that i'm trying to create

```
A(m, n) = A(m - 1, A(m, n - 1))
```

So here is my code:

```
    uint_type calculate(tuple_type const& args) const {

    uint_type retval;

        uint_type retval;

        auto second = make_tuple(m - 1, calculate(make_tuple(m, n - 1)));
        auto first = make_tuple(m - 1, second);
        retval = calculate(first);
        return retval;
       }
   };
```

and here is the error:

> error: no viable conversion from 'tuple<[...],
>   std::__1::tuple>' to 'const
>   tuple<[...], uint_type>'
>               retval = calculate(firstTuple);
>
> ^~~~~~~~~~emphasized text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type errors are sometimes hard to find if you use a lot of `auto` and template functions like `make_tuple`.  Here's how you'd write it with less use of `auto` and `make_tuple`:

```
uint_type calculate(tuple_type const& args) const {
    const uint_type m = get<0>(args);
    const uint_type n = get<1>(args);

    uint_type retval;

    tuple_type second{m - 1, calculate(tuple_type{m, n - 1})};
    tuple_type first{m - 1, second};
    //                      ^^^^^^ error
    retval = calculate(first);
    return retval;
}
```

You can see how adding a couple type annotations moved the error message exactly to where the error is.

However, that's not the Ackermann function.  This is the Ackermann function:

```
uint_type calculate(tuple_type args) const {
    const uint_type m = get<0>(args);
    const uint_type n = get<1>(args);
    if (m == 0)
        return n + 1;
    if (n == 0)
        return calculate(tuple_type{m - 1, 1});
    return calculate(tuple_type{m - 1, calculate(tuple_type{m, n - 1})});
}
```

Note that the `tuple_type` can be omitted:

```
uint_type calculate(tuple_type args) const {
    const uint_type m = get<0>(args);
    const uint_type n = get<1>(args);
    if (m == 0)
        return n + 1;
    if (n == 0)
        return calculate({m - 1, 1});
    return calculate({m - 1, calculate({m, n - 1})});
}
```

Comment: Thank you. You are awesome. off-topic: Is this an IDE bug ? http://i.imgur.com/6iqpTMt.png

Comment: I have no idea if I'd call it a bug.